# How to get second value variable in an array from dropdown selection in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope

I'm looking to get the variable of the second value in an array list that a user selects via dropdown in my controller to do some math functions.

```
$scope.dropdown = [
{name:'Name', value:'123'}]
```

So I'm looking to pull the 123 when a user selects "Name" from a dropdown. I'm aware of how I can do this on the front-end like:

```
<p> {{dropdown.value}} </p>
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it in the controller.

I've tried:

```
var variable = $scope.dropdown.value;
var variable = $scope.dropdown[0].value;
var variable = $scope.dropdown.value[0];
```

But none of it seems to work.

An example of what I'm working with right now is:

```
 $scope.input1 = "";

 var rate = 2;

 $scope.dropdown = [
  {name:'Name', value:'123'}
 ];

 var activities = (Number($scope.input1) * $scope.dropdownSelection.value * rate) / 2;

 console.log(activities);
```

So basically, I'm looking to perform math functions in the controller from user inputs and user dropdown selections along with defined variables and I can't seem to figure out how to get the users selected dropdown value in the array.

Answer (score 2):

The angular js way would be ideally using `$filter` and your controller code could be something like below

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

    //array
    var items = [{  id: "5", country: "UAE" }, { id: "4",  country: "India" }];

    //search value
    var id2Search = "4";

    //filter the array
    var foundItem = $filter('filter')(items, { id: id2Search  }, true)[0];

    //get the index
    var index = items.indexOf(foundItem );
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking to find the value that a user selected from the dropdown that is populated using a dropdown array at the controller.

Here is what something you could do.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.input1 = 1;
    $scope.dropdownValues = [{
      name: 'Name',
      value: 123
    }, {
      name: 'Name-1',
      value: 456
    }, {
      name: 'Name-2',
      value: 789
    }];

    $scope.dropdownValue = 123;
    var rate = 10;

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.dropdownValue
    }, function() {
      $scope.activities = (Number($scope.input1) * $scope.dropdownValue * rate) / 2;
    });

  }
]);
```

```css
div.value {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <select ng-model="dropdownValue">
      <option ng-repeat="item in dropdownValues" ng-value="item.value">
        {{item.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <div class="value">
      Selected Value : {{dropdownValue}}
    </div>

    <div>
      Activities : {{activities}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```